# custom "sales_order_item" attribute to API response

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, custom-attributes, sales-order-item

I followed [this](https://www.siphor.com/adding-custom-attributes-to-magento-2-quotes-and-orders/) guide to add a custom product attribute to quote and sales order item throughout the order process and this works fine.

My custom attribute is added to the `sales_order_item` **table** correctly but will not return in the order api call: `/rest/V1/orders/X` . The item in the order are present but the custom added attribute seems to be missing.

How do I add this `sales_order_item` attribute to the API output?

I tried it by adding a **"extension_attributes.xml"** to my custom module (that included the custom attribute: see earlier mentioned link) but that seems to have no effect:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface">
        <attribute code="deliverycode" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Thanks for the help!

**Update**

Still haven't resolved the issues after trying some minor things. I ran into [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267717/how-to-get-the-custom-order-attributes-in-default-order-api-response-in-magento?rq=1) topic, which is closely related to my issue. I am trying to adjust the code to suit my needs but I haven't found the answer yet after a few hours of trying to switch the code the be suitable for "sales_order_item". If anyone has any solutions or tips to push me in the right direction they are very much appreciated!

Comment: Have you got the above answer ??

Answer (score 0):

Hi,

Please try to get the order item rest/V1/orders/items/(orderid)

Or else add extension attributes in order api

```
1. create Vendor\Module\etc\extension_attributes.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
    <attribute code="order_attribute" type="string" />
</extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Then create observer for event ‘sales_order_load_after’

```
2. Vendor\Module\etc\events.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="sales_order_load_after">
    <observer name="sales_order_load_order_attribute" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Sales\OrderLoadAfter" />
</event>
</config>
```

Create a file to get the event data

```
3. vendor\Module\Observer\Sales\OrderLoadAfter.php

<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Sales;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class OrderLoadAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getOrder();
    $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
    if ($extensionAttributes === null) {
        $extensionAttributes = $this->getOrderExtensionDependency();
    }
    $attr = `Get the order item attributes`
    $extensionAttributes->setOrderAttribute($attr);
    $order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
}
private function getOrderExtensionDependency()
{
    $orderExtension = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
        '\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtension'
    );
    return $orderExtension;
}
}
```

Please run the upgrade, compile and deploy command

THanks

Comment: Hi, I am trying your suggestions, thanks! I think your code above relates to extending the **ORDERS** instead of the **ORDER ITEMS** that have a custom attribute (sales_order_items) am I correct in assuming so? I am trying to rewrite for it, no luck yet though.

Comment: Yes, We add the custom attribute in order. Probably, we can not add in the order_item directly. YOu need to use the order extension attributes to achieve that.

Comment: I do not quite understand. So in order to add my custom sales_order_item attribute to the API I will need to use an **order** extension instead of an **order item** extension (OrderItemInterface)? Thanks!

Comment: I looked into your code a bit further and I thank you for your effort, but I need to expose the custom **sales_order_item** attribute to the api and not a custom **sales_order** attribute. I am still looking into it, if I find a way I will post an update.

Comment: @JohnRP if you found an answer, you can always post it here and mark it as answered

Comment: Sadly I have not found an answer to this issue.

Comment: @JohnRP try https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/243721/74115

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine that you are implementing this for the order service.
Then, you request the following service to get a single order:

```
rest/V1/orders/:orderId
```

In fact you are requesting the **get** method of **OrderRepository**.

So in your extension_attributes.xml you already have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface">
        <attribute code="deliverycode" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

After doing that you need to implement you Plugin for the OrderRepository, where in your implementation you should follow the example down below:

```
<?php

namespace YourVendor\Sales\Plugin\Model;

class OrderRepository
{

    protected $orderItemExtension;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemExtensionInterfaceFactory $orderItemExtension
    )
    {
        $this->orderItemExtension = $orderItemExtension;
    }

    public function afterGet(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository $subject,
        $result
    )
    {
        foreach ($result->getItems() as $item) {
            $deliveryCode = ""; // whatever it comes from...

            $extensionAttributes = $this->orderItemExtension->create();
            $extensionAttributes->setData('deliverycode', $deliveryCode );
            $item->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Tested solution on 2.4 is as followings:

1. declare extension attribute for order items (in my case it was item_image) I want to add each item image url.

   <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface">

   ```
   <attribute code="item_image" type="string" />
   ```

   </extension_attributes>
2. Declare plugin for order item repository which is responsible to collect order items data

   ```
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ItemRepository">
    <plugin name="Alrajhi_FoodPickupApi_Plugin_Magento_Sales_Model_Order_ItemRepository" type="Alrajhi\FoodPickupApi\Plugin\Order\ItemImage\ItemRepository" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/></type>
   ```
3. write your logic in the plugin

namespace Alrajhi\FoodPickupApi\Plugin\Order\ItemImage;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface;

class ItemRepository
{

```
public function afterGetList(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ItemRepository $subject,
                                              $result,
                                              $searchCriteria
) {
    foreach ($result->getItems() as $item) {
        $this->setItemImage($item);
    }
    return $result;
}

/**
 * Set item image
 *
 * @param OrderItemInterface $item
 */
public function setItemImage(OrderItemInterface $item)
{
    $extensionAttributes = $item->getExtensionAttributes() ?: $this->orderExtensionFactory->create();
    $extensionAttributes->setItemImage("hassanalishahzad"); // here you can write you logic
    $item->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
}
```

}

This will now show you in the orders API response